# iOS app to read books from Calibre library store in iCloud drive

Tags: calibre, ios

I'm looking for an app (or apps), which can access and use Calibre library, stored in iCloud.

It was pretty easy to set up Calibre on both macOS and Windows to simply load the library from a directory in iCloud drive, but I cannot figure out a similar setup on my iPhone.

Comment: Nothing will read the library - but browsing into it you should be able to find the books (e.g. epubs) and they should be loadable in a reading app e,g, Marvin